# Base64 encode/decode large files in xml .net

Tags: .net, base64, decode, encode

i have a external webservice which returns the files in byte array (small, large 20Mb  file's), it has to be converted to base64 string and include in XML file

**Encode**

the code i used to convert the byte array to base64 is

```
 Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length, _
               Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```

the below is the actual xml construction i use Linq to XML.

```
    attachment = From Item In cpd _
      Select New XElement("attachment", _
          New XAttribute("id", Item.UniqueID), _
       New XElement("attachmentDocumentInformation", _
       New XElement("actor", New XAttribute("reference", Item.AttchRefId)), _
       New XElement("documentDescription", _
       New XElement("documentTitle", Item.Document), _
       New XElement("documentType", "A"), _
       New XElement("sequence", Item.Sequence))), _
       New XElement("documentContent", _
         New XAttribute("contentEncoding", "base64"), _
         New XAttribute("id", "DocumentContent" + Item.UniqueID), _
         New XAttribute("mimeType", Item.mimeType), _ 
                 Convert.ToBase64String(Item.Content, 0, Item.Content.Length, _ 
                 Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)))
```

**Decode**

and i use frombase64 conversion for the received xml file

```
 Convert.FromBase64String(documentContentinBase64)
```

it works fine when the file's are smaller size, when it's a large file conversion returns "No such interface supported".

I have two questions:

1. what is the best way to convert large files tobase64/frombase64 ?
2. after converting the byte array to base64 what is the best way to construct xml file with base64 documents in it. Does anyone have some code?

Thanks

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String` does not have a signature like that. Can you please confirm your code?

Comment: When you say "blows up," what do you mean; is there an exception?  If so, post the contents of the exception.

Comment: Also assuming at this point bContent is JUST the value of the `documentContent` node? Why not serialize an object and let the `XmlSerializer` do all the work for you?

Comment: yes bcontent in encoding is bytearray and bcontent in decoding is base64string. including a document is a small part in xml file and there are more attributes and xml documents included within this xml package and i was not sure of xmlserializer i will look in to this.

Comment: jacob- i get the following "No such interface supported"

Comment: Serialising 20Mb files into a base64 encoded string in an XML doc sounds like a bad way of doing things... Are you sure you can't just include a link that can be used to retrieve the file itself in a secondary process in binary format?

Comment: this is the format our client accepts, so i have to follow their standards. the client accepts the XML package Up to 20Mb and this contains base64 documents(it can be 3Mb,5Mb,7Mb doc's in the package, the reason i said the file size 20Mb coz there can be a single 18Mb file and it's a valid package for the client to accept)

Answer (score 1):

This roughly follows your document, simple massage some names, or add xml serializer attributes to get the xml document you want:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Actor { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string type { get { return "A"; } }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}


var d = new Document() { Actor = "Sean Connory", Description = "Thriller", Title = "The Rock" };
d.Content = new byte[] { 43,45,23,43,82,90,34 };

var xmls = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    xmls.Serialize(ms, d);
    Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

the `XmlSerializer` will convert the `byte[]` property (in this case Content) automatically to and from base64encoding. You were looking for the 'best' way to convert large files and to put them in xml documents. Their my be other (better) ways of doing so. But I have used this way with a great amount of success in the past. If setup correctly this solution could save you a lot of trouble as it will both build the xml document for you and convert the data to Base64 if the object is setup correctly. On the reverse side you can take an xml document and populate an object with all of its data which saves you the time of navigating xml nodes to find the data you want.

**Update**

If this doesn't work for large files as expected, I did find [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform.aspx) on serializing a stream into a base64 stream. I have never worked with this before and so cannot provide any sort of great insight for you but it sounds more like something you are looking for.

Comment: Just to check is this a suggestion not on how to use Base64 but an alternative way of serializing the file that should be more robust? You might want to provide some more explanation because my first thought was "downvote since it doesn't seem to have anythign to do with base64 encoding".

Comment: Yeah, my point was more that you might want to explain that is what you are doing in the answer itself. On its own it isn't obvious what exactly it is that you are suggesting.

Comment: using XMLSerializer i was able to successfully process the small file's however larger file's i was unsuccessful. i tried `Debug.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()))` and saw it on debug output window it was constructing the base64string at some point it stopped, i don't get any error and the output window doesn't show the content element but has other element and values. i'm i missing something here ?